# Libgdx AndroidAudio recorder

Tags: android, libgdx, audio-recording

When trying to initialize an AndroidAudioRecorder my app crashes with this error:

```
 Unable to initialize AudioRecorder. Do you have the RECORD_AUDIO permission
```

The AndroidManifest includes this line

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Here is the Recorder class

```
public class AndroidAudioRecorder implements AudioRecorder {

private AudioRecord recorder;

public AndroidAudioRecorder (int samplingRate, boolean isMono) {

    int channelConfig = isMono ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplingRate, channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, samplingRate, channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            minBufferSize);

    if (recorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        recorder.startRecording();
}


@Override
public void dispose () {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
}

@Override
public void read (short[] samples, int offset, int numSamples) {
    int read = 0;
    while (read != numSamples) {
        read += recorder.read(samples, offset + read, numSamples - read);
    }
}
```

}

And this is where it is being initialized

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

private final int screenWidth = 480;
private final int screenHeight = 800;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    AudioRecorder r = new AndroidAudioRecorder(44100, true);
    initialize(new MyApp(screenWidth, screenHeight, r), config);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that you have placed the permission tags outside the <application> tag?

Comment: Or maybe try something like the following: `if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_MICROPHONE);

}`

Comment: It is outside the application tag. where would I add that line?

Comment: I would add that code (to request permission on runtime), before I initialize the AndroidAudioRecorder. The best way to do so is to implement a listener/interface, like it is decribed [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).